# Why does my C# Random not create any random number?

Tags: c#

I am using the following code:

```
var a = (new Random()).Next(2);
```

This is inside of a small loop.  Each time it sets the value of a to zero. Can someone give me some advice on what I am doing wrong?

Update

Thanks for the advice given but I still see just the one number:-(  Here is my code after I added the suggestions:

```
        var r1 = new Random();
        var r2 = new Random();

        foreach (var entry in this.ChangeTracker.Entries()
                     .Where(
                          e => e.Entity is IAuditableTable &&
                         (e.State == EntityState.Added) ||
                         (e.State == EntityState.Modified)))
        {
            IAuditableTable e = (IAuditableTable)entry.Entity;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                e.CreatedBy = r1.Next(2);
                e.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * r2.Next(30));
            }
            e.ModifiedBy = r1.Next(2);
            e.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * r2.Next(30));
        }
```

Always the CreatedBy and ModifiedBy get a 0 :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move random creation out of the loop:

```
var random = new Random();

foreach(var item in items)
{ 
   var a = random.Next(2);
   // ...
}
```

Because new random instance is initialized with [Environment.TickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx), i.e. milliseconds from last machine start, thus if you are creating them too fast, random instances will have same seed (which means instances will return exactly same 'random' values):

```
public Random() : this(Environment.TickCount)
{
}
```

*too fast* means within 16 milliseconds, between updates of Environment.TickCount value.

Comment: Thanks. I did this but I still notice the same (always zero) value. I updated the question with the actual code. Do you have any ideas. I don't know what else to try.

Comment: @Melina `Next(2)` means only two possible values `0` and `1`. Your code should work now - try to run it several times.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:

```
var random = new Random();
while (true)
{
  var a = random.Next(2);
  // use a
}
```